# Possible to create Visual Studio project with Output Type of "none"?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and would like to create a sort of container project that holds a number of DLL's that must be installed with a solution. I want them to be in a separate project so that they can be easily attached to a solution as a group.

I created an empty project call TEST, added my DLL's to it with a Build Action of "Content", and set them to "Copy Always". That all works exactly as I want. The problem is that if I set the TEST project Output Type to "Console Application" or "Windows Application" that it won't build because there's no entry point. If I set the Output Type to "Class Library", it builds but I end up with an extra TEST.DLL file that I don't really want.

Is there anyway to sort of set the Output Type to "none"? I want the build actions to take place (so my DLL's get copied) but I don't want the dummy class assembly created. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Assumptions for the following step-by-step guide:

Let's assume that you have a solution with two projects:

- `Main`: your main (start-up) project.
- `BundledDLLs`: a library project which contains the `.dll`s that should end up in the main project's output directory.

### Step-by-step guide:

The easiest way to achieve your goal inside Visual Studio is probably the following:

1. **Add all `.dll`s to `BundledDLLs` and set their *Copy to output directory* to *Copy if newer*.**

   This is done in the *Project Explorer* and the *Properties* windows.
2. **Configure `BundledDLLs`'s output directory to be identical to `Main`'s output directory.**

   This can be done in the *Build* tab of `BundledDLL`'s *Project Properties* page. Enter something like the following in the *Output Path* textbox:

   ```
   ..\Main\bin\Debug
   ```
3. **Set up `BundledDLLs` as a dependency of `Main`.**

   *Do not* add `BundledDLLs` as a project reference to `Main`, as you usually might; instead, use the *Project Dependencies* dialog to . This will tell the build tool that whenever `Main` is built, `BundledDLLs` needs to be built first.

   Do this by right-clicking on the `Main` project node to open the context menu; select *Project dependencies...* from there. In the now opened dialog, first select `Main` from the drop-down list; then check `BundledDLLs` in the project list below. `BundledDLLs` is now registered as a dependency of `Main`.

   > **P.S.:** One disadvantage of *not* having an explicit assembly reference in `Main` is that some tooling might not recognise the dependency. For example, ClickOnce deployment might not work properly.
4. **Add a post-build event to `BundledDLLs` that deletes the superfluous `BundledDLLs.dll`.**

   As you said, you don't want, and don't need, the dummy output generated when `BundledDLLs` is built. So add a post-build event that simply deletes this `.dll` once it's been created.

   Open the *Build events* tab in `BundledDLLs`'s *Project Properties* page, and enter something like the following in the post-build textbox:

   ```
   DEL "$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).*"
   ```

   (In case you wondered: The reason why you didn't add this project as a project reference to `Main` earlier is because if you had done so, `Main` would be looking for `BundledDLLs.dll`, which it wouldn't be able to find since you don't actually want such a file to be generated.)

   > **P.S.:** One disadvantage of adding such a post-build step is that it might interfere with incremental builds. If your project keeps getting recompiled from scratch after this, you might be better off removing the post-build step and living with the extra `BundledDLLs.dll` in your solution's output directory.

Comment: Could you elaborate on, when you don't add BundledDLLs as a project reference to Main, how you'd reference classes of BundledDLLs from inside your code in Main? Thanks!

Comment: *@jan:* If you want to use a class or another type, you simply add an assembly reference to the project, as you always would. However, this is not what this question, nor my answer, are about: I only show how you set up a project that does nothing more than copy some DLLs to the output directory. This can become necessary, e.g. when the build system cannot determine dependencies on some DLLs automatically. (This can happen e.g. when your code resolves and loads assemblies at run-time using Reflection, or when your solution includes unmanaged code.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a makefile project, which doesn't require you to build/link anything.

In your project properties (right click property in solution explorer and click "Properties"),  under "Configuration Properties" and then under "General", choose "Makefile" from the "Configuration Type" drop-down menu.  The build output will include the warning "The property 'NMakeBuildCommandLine' doesn't exist...Skipping" but the build will succeed without building any dll/exe/etc.

While other answers here may better address your specific need, specifying a makefile more directly answers the question title "Possible to create Visual Studio project with Output Type of none?"  I hope this is useful for people who google something to that effect and land here.

Credit goes to Xeek in the #winapi freenode irc channel for sharing this tip.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting them in a project, you can put the files in a [Solution Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28VS.80%29.aspx).  One of your projects can have a build action that does the copying, but since they won't be in a project, they won't try to "build".

Comment: I originally thought of answering with this as well, but our team had to abandon solution folders because the upkeep was tremendous across multiple solution files.  We ended up doing what the OP is doing and ignoring the generated .dll :/

Comment: As "womp" suggested, I was hoping to keep the DLL stuff encapsulated entirely within their own project and not have to do maintenance somewhere else as well. I'm inclined to just ignore the junk DLL as well (it's only 3K after all). It just seems sort of "messy" this way. I'm doing this is for the SQL Server Compact Edition assemblies incidentally.